# Suppress make clock skew warning when using NFS and NTP is unavailable

Tags: c++, time, makefile

This question has been asked several times, yet not actually answered.

I'm using Putty to connect to a university Linux box.  This server's clock is 15 minutes behind.  My home directory is an NFS mount.

The BOFH has not configured NTP, even after several requests.

I can use the touch command until the sun turns blue; make will still warn.

Comment: Yup. 'Lassie is trying to tell you something.' If you can't fix the clocks, you are stuck with the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used it by myself, but have you checked http://nfstimesync.sourceforge.net/ project?